# How would closing borders and supply routes affect local market prices?

Tags: equipment, campaign-development, campaign-settings

I'm developing a world where governments are freaking out over a perceived threat (not a virus). The stars have disappeared and the gods have seemingly abandoned them. Many leaders have ordered their borders locked down and trade routes closed for various reasons.

Different countries would have the resources they can produce themselves (obviously) but things from outside would be increasingly scarce as time goes on. I know that not having shipments to a desert country would raise the price of the remaining wood products in their markets. But I don't know how much. I know what each country produces and what they import.

**My question:**
What is a reasonable scale for increasing scarcity?

I'm mostly looking for a realistic percentage I can add to market prices every week/month to reflect the scarcity. But if a set scale is more realistic let me know.

**P.S.**
I know my PCs will be able to exploit this with smuggling and get "hella rich" as they would put it. But in the long run if they waste their time smuggling they will come to the inevitable end of the campaign with too much money and not enough power. I'm letting them know it's on a timeline so they can make their own decisions.

Comment: I think this question would be better suited to the Worldbuilding Stack

Comment: Yeah, this isn't really in our wheel house. It is about RPGs in the sense that you will be using this world for your game, but you will likely get a much better response at worldbuilding.se. I flagged for mod attention so they can get it moved.

Comment: Hmm... So admittedly I'm not a fan of migrations in general, they tend to cause more issue than they're worth. If this was/is off-topic here, it might be worth it, but I don't think this question is. But even then, I think parts of this would need to be rewritten for WB because the question currently assumes familiarity with RPGs and part of this question have RPG-aspects integrated to them. On that note, it would probably benefit from specify its system, but I'm not sure if it's necessary. Leaving an open note, WB might give you better *in frame* answers, though.

Comment: This may seem harsh, but I'm voting to close for clarity. Part of it is because this is very much going to depend on what system you're using, as how much the economy is part of the game will vary with different systems (and for all we know, the system you're using may already have rules for this very thing; we've seen it happen).

Comment: The other part of it is that I'm not clear on the intended outcome of the calamity here. This feels like it could be either "What challenges can a party expect to face due to the world economy locking down?" or "How can I present appropriate and effective challenges to the party based on the world economy locking down?", depending on whether you're asking from a realism or gameplay perspective.

Comment: WB could close this as Too Story Based.